# How to send large text in AJAX Request using prototype?

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

I have a situation where I have to send a large text in ajax request using method :POST. I have tried to do like this.

```
 new Ajax.Request(url + "?" + params, {
                method: 'post',postBody: {'Test':'Test'}, onSuccess: function (transport) {
                    switch (transport.responseJSON.Status) {
                        case "Success":
                            // alert(transport.responseJSON.Message);
                            var imgDiv = document.getElementById(control);
                            imgDiv.style.display = 'none';
                            break;
                        case "Failed":
                            alert(transport.responseJSON.Message);
                            break;
                        case "NotAuthorized":
                            alert(transport.responseJSON.Message);
                            break;
                        case "LoginRequired":
                            window.location = transport.responseJSON.RedirectAfterLogin;
                            break;

                    }

                }
            });
```

Test in post body will be replaced with large text from a text area. But when I try to access it on server like this

```
string test = context.Request["Test"];
```

I get null.
Any solution reference to an example?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
postbody:'Test=Test'
```

instead of

```
postbody: {'Test':'Test'}
```

As your text is large, so use `escape()` function so that it is transmitted to server safely. Also be sure that your query string and post body params not clash with each other.

Answer (score 1):

postBody is expected to be a name/value pair like this:

```
postbody:'Test=Test'
```

You would also need to add `evalJSON = true` if you want to use `responseJSON` assuming your returned content type is actually JSON